# When is it enough to consider roofs in the derived category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, model-categories, derived-categories, differential-graded-algebras

In the derived category $D^b(\mathcal{A})$ of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, obtained by taking the Verdier quotient wrt. all quasi-isomorphism, a morphism is given by a roof (or span) $ X\stackrel{\sim}{\leftarrow} A \to Y$. The composition with a morphism $Y \stackrel{\sim}{\leftarrow} B \to Z$ can be written as the roof

$$\begin{matrix} &&&& A\times_Y B\\
&&& \swarrow && \searrow\\
&& A &&&& B\\
& \swarrow && \searrow && \swarrow && \searrow\\
X &&&& Y &&&& Z.\end{matrix}$$

This derived category $D^b(\mathcal{A})$ can be seen as the homotopy category of the model category $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal{A})$, which has quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences. In general, however, homotopy categories need not have roof as morphisms, but general zig zags $X \stackrel{\sim}{\leftarrow} A_1\to B_1 \stackrel{\sim}{\leftarrow} A_2\to B_2 \stackrel{\sim}{\leftarrow} \dotsb \to Y$.

How do I know when it is enough to consider roofs only? I would have guessed that it is enough if the model category has pullbacks and those preserve weak equivalences.

But I have been told that the derived category dga algebras does not have only roots as morphisms—this contradicts my expectations, as dga algebras should have pullbacks preserving quasi-isomorphisms—or don't they?

Comment: You want to search "calculus of fractions" in google, the nLab entry gives you the conditions on the class of weak equivalences so that the homotopy category can be described using roofs (aka as spans) https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions

Comment: this question is related : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88630/do-weak-equivalences-in-a-model-category-admit-a-calculus-of-fractions

Comment: @jeanmfischer Is it obvious that for dga-algebras the quasi-isomorphisms admit no calculus of fractions?

Comment: I have not thought about it yet. The thing is the model category of bounded chain complexes does not admit a calculus of fractions either, from what I recall you have to pass to an intermediate category, some $K(\mathcal{A})$, to get the calculus of fractions.

Comment: But I think it is cumbersome, if you have a model category, the description of the homotopy category using the subcategory of fibrant-cofibrant objects and quotient it by homotopy relations is quite effective. Why do you need a calculus of fractions ?

Comment: @jeanmfischer Mostly, out of curiousity—I was confronted with that claim and I am astonished by it, because I had this construction from chain complexes in mind.